# Not getting any MIUI update after 14.0.2 on Redmi Note 13 Pro+

Tags: updates, xiaomi, miui, redmi

Not getting any MIUI update after 14.0.2 on Redmi Note 13 Pro+.

I bought a Redmi Note 13 Pro+ Indian Global variant last month. I am not getting any MIUI update notifications. Also, if I check for update manually, it says `No update available`. My current MIUI version is 14.0.2. Now is it normal?

I saw in some article that HyperOS is now available for Redmi Note 13 Pro+ Indian Global variant. What should I do?

Comment: Is your phone branded in a way by a mobile network operator? What value do you see in Android settings on the Android patch level date? This date is usually a good indicator how old the installed update is.

Comment: Could you link to the article? Was the HyperOS update to Redmi Note 13 Pro+ very recently? Otherwise, [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_13_pro+-12572.php) still shows the latest version is MIUI 14, not HyperOS. It could be outdated or not, I don't know. There was also [a review](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_13_pro+-reviews-12572.php) on 10 Mar by Richy Logitech mentioning the lack of Android 14 or HyperOS.

Comment: @AndrewT. finally got the update.